# Get a json array with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I want to get an array that I used with Ajax. I already used this method with an other page and this time it doesn't work, so I don't see where is the problem.

I have an array :

```
var array_downloads = <?php echo json_encode($array_downloads);?>;
```

This array isn't empty, when I do a `console.log` I get the content, the list of the elements.

After that, I make my Ajax request like that :

```
$.post("pack.php", {arr:array_downloads}, function(data) { 
...
},'json');
```

So I send my array to the file `.php`.

Finally I want to get the array with this :

```
$array_downloads = $_POST["arr"];
```

And when I try to echo it (and I don't forget the `json_encode()`), I get `null`.
I don't understand why.
Help please !

Comment: echo this `file_get_contents("php://input")` and share results. That's the raw data sent to PHP's $_POST

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar It displays nothing :/

Comment: This might not be the cause of the bug, but I'm pretty sure that the way you're calling $.post automatically converts the object to a query string, not a JSON string. You need to either stringify your object, or tell JQuery not to convert it. See "processData" at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  .

Comment: for debugging purposes try: var_dump ($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0):

I tries with the same code and it works as it is suppose to:

> The only code I changed is wrapped `json_encode` output in quotes so that `javascript` will consider it as a string.

**main.php**

```
<?php $array_downloads = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; ?>
<script>
    var array_downloads = '<?php echo json_encode($array_downloads);?>';
    $.post("pack.php", {arr: array_downloads}, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }, 'json');
</script>
```

**pack.php**

```
<?php
var_dump(json_decode($_REQUEST['arr'],true));
?>
```

**Output in pack.php**

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 2
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 4
  4 => int 5
```

Comment: But the var_dump displays an empty array for me

Comment: So you can get the array but I don't, I get an empty array in the pack.php. I don't know why :/

Comment: Just chack what data is being transmitted over server in `network tab-developer tools`

Comment: I just tried your code, but without the quotes and I got an array in `$_POST["arr"]`

Comment: @gre_gor, In the case without `quotes`, Data transmitted is an `object`,not a `string`. It will be like: `arr[]:1
arr[]:2
arr[]:3
arr[]:4
arr[]:5`  Sending string over server seems more appropriate..

Comment: Ok, I must have a problem somewhere else :/

Comment: @RayonDabre I know, PHP automaticaly parses this into an array and that's exactly what @Erlaunis wants. In your case you need to call `json_decode` on `$_POST["arr"]` to get an array.